# Custom merge field in link URL in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

I'm wanting to include a custom (dropdown) field in an image link's url:

```
http://*|URL:CUSTOMURL|*/something.html
```

How do I test it? It doesn't seem to be working in the previews. When I send myself a preview email, I see the image but it is not linked with a url. Same when I go to preview mode from the editor.

UPDATE: When I view the email's source in the editor, this is what I see:

```
<a href="https://*|URL:CLIENTURL|*/admin/orders.aspx" target="_blank">
 <img align="none" height="34" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/4fafa4303a13a91579f6c0607/images/11d12752-8c53-4e61-a846-11398c3b1b31.jpg" style="width: 253px; height: 34px; margin: 0px;" width="253" />
</a>
```

And when I view the source in the preview email, this is what I see:

```
<a style="color:#336699;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline">
 <img align="none" height="34" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/tdjDklxdP33lZw9-uFxY6UuirteMRp2jEeNlKgMCyX0kVsMwAM-4yN2XKuQbf3FlfmdlN0MhMHSOoC0f0AbKNlvdi_3pZUjKnwv6qjU7lhti2pkUHRkyWpcsfQyHQD4Nhy-eNynjkUPWcuuckg2SmzzDdSf53zCwERCQGT4=s0-d-e1-ft#https://gallery.mailchimp.com/4fafa4303a13a91579f6c0607/images/11d12752-8c53-4e61-a846-11398c3b1b31.jpg" style="width:253px;min-height:34px;margin:0px;border:0;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none;display:inline" width="253" class="CToWUd">
</a>
```

And when I view the source on the preview page, this is what I see:

```
<a href="https://%26lt%3B%26lt%3B+Test+Interested+in+a+specific+Peer+Giving+site%3F+%26gt%3B%26gt%3B/admin/orders.aspx" target="_blank" style="color: #336699;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">
 <img align="none" height="34" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/4fafa4303a13a91579f6c0607/images/11d12752-8c53-4e61-a846-11398c3b1b31.jpg" style="width: 253px;height: 34px;margin: 0px;border: 0;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;" width="253">
</a>
```

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot this without seeing your full code.

Comment: I simplified the question so that it's more specific, and added the markup in question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to just save the email as a template and send it to just me (not through preview, but through the final confirm and send). I verified that my custom fields were working that way.